# HTML5 History API - The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, html

I save the page of this simple demo for HTML5 History API from http://www.murraypicton.com/playground/animating-the-address-bar.html

and open it in locally. Firefox gives me "The operation is insecure" and Chrome gives me nothing when I clicked "Start". Why and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used a server, it works. Using wamp. So means cannot run w/o a server. Wonder if anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy in Web Server and open it. If you directly open it from a directory to web browser you may get this error.